# Converting a JSON file to NSMutableDictionary in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode

I have a json file that looks like this:

```
{
    "data": 
    {
        "level": [
            {
            //bunch of stuff
            }
            ]
    }
}
```

Now I want to convert that into a array of levels that I can access. If I take away the `{"data:` part, then I can use this:

```
NSData *allLevelsData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileLoc];
NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableDictionary *allLevels = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:allLevelsData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
if(!error){
        NSMutableArray *level = allLevels[@"level"];
        for (NSMutableDictionary *aLevel in level){
            //do stuff with the level...
```

But I have to have the `{"data:` as part of the file, and I can't figure out how to get a NSData object out of the existing NSData object. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need to pull the `level` NSArray out of the `data` NSDictionary first?

```
NSData *allLevelsData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileLoc];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:allLevelsData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
if(!error){
    NSArray *levels = dataDictionary[@"data"][@"level"];
    for (NSDictionary *aLevel in levels){
        //do stuff with the level...
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You won't get mutable objects back by default and declaring the variables as mutable doesn't make them so. Take a mutableCopy of the result instead (assuming you really *do* need mutability).
2. Why are you trying to prune ahead of time? If you decode the original JSON, you'll be able to extract the level array from the data dict in the decoded dict.

It's not clear what else you're trying to accomplish or why you are going the path you ask about. Note, this doesn't *necessarily* mean your path is wrong, just that without a clearer indication of what goal you're really trying to accomplish or what you've **actually** tried (and errored/failed, along with how it failed), you're likely only to get vague/general answers like this.

Comment: I guess my basic question is: how do I get an array of levels (each level is an NSDictionary) from a json file that looks like that? It's the extra json layer "data" that's throwing me off.

Comment: Assume the value of the key "level" already is an array, which it appears to be, based on your provided JSON. When you decode this JSON, you'll have a dictionary with at least an entry with key "data". If you want to step-by-step it, you decode the JSON you get a dict, call it allDict. Extract the dict with key "data" from allDict, call it dataDict. Then extract the array with key "level" from dataDict.